# Reading and writing vendor-specific BLE characteristic values using bluetoothctl or gatttool

Tags: bluez, gatttool, bluetoothctl

I am able to connect to and read vendor-specific characteristic values from a BLE device using gatttool on a Raspberry Pi 4B terminal command line, but I have a couple of issues.

1. A dialog appears, "Connection successful", with an OK button. I do not think this will be acceptable in production code.
2. I am unable to "unpair" or "remove" the device using gatttool.

I am able to connect to a BLE device using bluetoothctl on a Raspberry Pi 4B terminal command line (interactive), and can read generic characteristic values, but I cannot read vendor-specific characteristic values. I can, however, remove (unpair) the device using bluetoothctl.

Using gatttool:
gatttool -t random -b E0:0D:10:F1:D5:FC --char-read -a 0x0014 returns the value of the characteristic.

Using bluetoothctl:
power on
scan on
pair E0:0D:10:F1:D5:FC
connect E0:0D:10:F1:D5:FC
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0001                    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0027
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0001/char0002           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0029
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0001/char0002/desc0004  /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char002b
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0001/char0005           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char002d
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0001/char0007           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char002f
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010                    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0031
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0011           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0033
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0013           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0035
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0015           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0037
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0017           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0039
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0019           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char003b
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char001b           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char003d
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char001d           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service003f
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char001f           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service003f/char0040
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0021           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service003f/char0042
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0023           /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service003f/char0042/desc0044
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0010/char0025
[rSY?1T5WpDnQg==r#nRoZXaLm1Dc5_]# select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service10/char0013
[rSY?1T5WpDnQg==r#nRoZXaLm1Dc5_]#

I thought perhaps the prompt would change to the selected attribute.

[rSY?1T5WpDnQg==r#nRoZXaLm1Dc5_]# read
No attribute selected
[rSY?1T5WpDnQg==r#nRoZXaLm1Dc5_]#

I thought maybe the read command would return the value of the characteristic, but that did not happen.

However, when I select a generic attribute,

[rSY?1T5WpDnQg==r#nRoZXaLm1Dc5_:/service0001/char0005]# select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0001/char0007
[rSY?1T5WpDnQg==r#nRoZXaLm1Dc5_:/service0001/char0007]# read
Attempting to read /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0001/char0007
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_0D_10_F1_D5_FC/service0001/char0007 Value:
fd df 10 72 3e f3 f0 84 b5 df 9e f1 3a a8 85 44  ...r>.......:..D
fd df 10 72 3e f3 f0 84 b5 df 9e f1 3a a8 85 44  ...r>.......:..D

the prompt changes and the characteristic value is returned.

I was hoping to find a good GATT tutorial on the internet. So far, all I seem to be able to find is the man pages (https://www.mankier.com/1/bluetoothctl).

Does anyone have suggestions on what BLE GATT tool to use and how to use it or references to online documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Before using a technology, you should try to understand it. Each BLE characteristic is described by different attributes, which might define a Characteristic as write-only, for example. However, you might want to start with the material provided by the Bluetooth SIG, for example: [Intro to Bluetooth Generic Attribute Profile (GATT)](https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/intro-to-bluetooth-gap-gatt/)

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to understand a technology before using it. And, yes, some of the characteristics are write-only. Thanks for the link to the Bluetooth SIG.

Comment: I would still like to know if anyone has suggestions on what BLE GATT tool to use and references for that tool.

Comment: Since BlueZ is the default Bluetooth stack on Linux, `bluetoothctl` is the way to go. Ressources are available all over the net, for example: 
https://www.bluez.org/
https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/bluetooth-for-linux/
https://github.com/bluez/